# PHP FTP Not Working Using Passive Mode

Tags: php, ftp

I have a script that was working before, but we recently changed the FTP location and is no longer working correctly.  I have tried setting to passive mode and switching between ascii / binary with no luck.

Below is my script, is there something obvious I'm missing?  Is there a way to easily identify the error?  The specified directory has all permissions.  It connects just fine and I can list the directory contents and see all the folders correctly...just doesn't upload.

```
$file = $createdAt.".txt";
$fp = fopen('exportorder/'.$file, 'r');

$conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.location.com') or die("Couldn't connect to ftp.location.com");;
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'pass');

ftp_pasv($conn_id,TRUE);
ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/OTD-0000117'); 

if (ftp_fput($conn_id, 'exportorder/'.$file, $fp, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sidenote: It won't fix the problem, but you can remove the extra semi-colon in `ftp.location.com");;` and try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if that renders anything; if error reporting isn't on by default.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't display any errors :/  Any other way to find out what the reason is for not being successful?

Comment: Besides checking your server logs, no I don't. Is there any way you can test this on another server?

Answer (score 0):

Use ftp_put that will dump the file from source to target if there is no change between source and target file.